# Google Monitoring API : Get Values

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-client

I'm trying to use the [Google Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) to retrieve metrics about my cloud usage. I'm using the Google Client Library for Python.

The API advertises the ability to access over 900 Stackdriver Monitoring Metrics. I am interested in accessing some Google App Engine metrics, such as Instance count, total memory, etc. The Google API Metrics page has a list of all the metrics I should be able to access.

I've followed the guides on the Google Client Library page , but my script making the API calls is not printing the metrics, it is just printing the metric descriptions.

How do I use the Google Monitoring API to access the metrics, rather than the descriptions?

My Code:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
...
response = monitor.projects().metricDescriptors().get(name='projects/{my-project-name}/metricDescriptors/appengine.googleapis.com/system/instance_count').execute()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc88B.png)

I expect to see the actual instance count. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone reading this, I figured out the problem. I was assuming the values would come from the 'metric descriptors' class in the api, but that was a poor assumption.

For values, you need to use a 'timeSeries' call. For this call, you need to specify the project you want to monitor, start time, end time, and a filter (the metric you want, such as cpu, memory, etc.)

So, to retrieve the app engine project memory, the above code becomes

```
request = monitor.projects().timeSeries().list(name='projects/my-appengine-project',
                                        interval_startTime='2016-05-02T15:01:23.045123456Z',
                                        interval_endTime='2016-06-02T15:01:23.045123456Z', 
                                        filter='metric.type="appengine.googleapis.com/system/memory/usage"')

response = request.execute()
```

This example has the start time and end time to cover a month of data.