# How to fetch number of reads and writes of Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way (maybe through an API or something) that can be used to fetch the number of reads (0/50,000) and writes (0/20,000) of the Cloud Firestore database so that there won't be a need to log in the firebase console separately and the user will keep track from within the app itself?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no straighforward way to obtain the number of reads and writes from a Cloud Firestore database via the Google Cloud Console or Firebase Console dashboards, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#usage_dashboard).

However, you can leverage [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring) to create custom Cloud Firestore metrics of usage. Monitoring provides the [Cloud Monitoring API v3](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3) which can help you retrieve the number of reads and writes in your database. Check out the list of [Firestore metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firestore).

Other stackoverflow questions that can help you with the process include:

- [How get a metric sample from monitoring APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550776/how-get-a-metric-sample-from-monitoring-apis)
- [Google Monitoring API : Get Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488956/google-monitoring-api-get-values)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public documented API for getting Firestore usage statistics from a Firebase project.  Feel free to send your idea as a [feature request to Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).